# Unable to perform any action using phantomjs watirwebdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I am unable to perform any actions like filling a text box, clicking a button, etc, on a webpage by using phantomjs webdriver headless execution.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b=Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
b.goto "google.com"
b.title # Google
b.text_field(:id => "lst-ib").set "Avinash"
```

So while filling the text box, I am facing the below issue.

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element,
using {:id=>"lst-ib", :tag_name=>"input or textarea", :type=>"(any
text type)"}    from
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.10/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:508:in
`assert_exists'     from
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.10/lib/watir-webdriver/user_editable.rb:11:in
`set'   from (irb):16   from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

The same scripts works fine while using firefox without headless execution. Please let me know if any suggestions here.

Below are my gem versions: 
1. watir-webdriver (0.6.10)
2. selenium-webdriver (2.45.0, 2.43.0)
3. phantomjs 2.0.0

Comment: No success. Same is the case even after maximising the browser.

Comment: I don't use phantomjs, and there isn't much information to go off of in the error you gave. I'd suggest updating to the latest watir-webdriver version (0.7.0), but that is unlikely to be your actual problem.

Comment: try using `:name => 'q'` instead.  what's the result? also, you've validated that `b.title` is `"Google"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that the HTML seen by PhantomJS differs from Firefox.

In Firefox the text field's HTML is:

```
<input spellcheck="false" dir="ltr" style="border: medium none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; background: url(&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 6; left: 0px; outline: medium none;" aria-autocomplete="both" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false" class="gsfi lst-d-f" id="lst-ib" maxlength="2048" name="q" autocomplete="off" title="Search" value="" aria-label="Search" type="text">
```

In contrast PhantomJS shows:

```
<input style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 8px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 6px; vertical-align: top; outline-style: none; outline-width: initial; outline-color: initial; " autocomplete="off" class="lst" value="" title="Google Search" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false">
```

Notice that PhantomJS does not have the id attribute. As a result, it makes sense that locating the field by its ID fails.

You will need to use a different locator. For example:

```
b.text_field(:name => "q").set("Avinash")
```

or

```
b.text_field(:title => "Google Search").set("Avinash")
```